# Proof by induction $nx^n<1$

Tags: limits, induction

I'm having trouble with this induction, and I'm not sure how to use the inductive step to my advantage in solving this problem.

So I need to prove $nx^n<1$, where $n$ is a natural number (N1), and $0<x<1/2$.

The basecase worked out, and in the inductive hypothesis I just changed $n$ to $k$. So we got $kx^k<1$.

Now the inductive step, I got $(k+1)x^{k+1}>1$, and I'm having trouble understanding how to use the inductive hypothesis. Should I manipulate the hypothesis in to a form where it can be plugged in? Should I make a triangle inequality?

I'm very lost with this so any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

$$(k+1)x^{k+1} = (kx^k) \times x + x^{k+1}$$

Comment: You will need to use $0 < x < \frac12$

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion for a simpler proof:

First note that hypothesis on $x$ imply that
$$0<nx^n<\frac n{2^n}, $$
so all you have to prove is that $\dfrac n{2^n}<1$ for all $n\in\mathbf N$.

Another observation: $\dfrac{n}{2^n}$ is decreasing for all $n\ge 1$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you get $\left(k + 1\right) x ^ {k + 1} > 1$.
You should get $\left(k + 1\right) x ^ {k + 1} = k x ^ {k + 1} + x ^ {k + 1} < x + x ^ {k + 1} = x \left(1 + x ^ k\right) < \dfrac{1}{2} \left(1 + \dfrac{1}{2 ^ k}\right) = \dfrac{2 ^ k + 1}{2 ^ {k + 1}} < 1$.